# What is this manga about a guy who completed a video and he gets a mysterious game?

Tags: gamerz-heaven

This is a manga that I read quite a while ago, maybe 5+ years. It starts off with a guy who completed a video and he gets a mysterious game that he has never seen before. He puts it into his console and nothing seems to happen. Then the class representive arrives outside his house. She suddenly turns into a monster which our protagonist somehow defeat. He exits the game and the next day when he goes to school the class rep is replaced by a guy. The girl class rep is gone and no one remember her. Then there's something about an area boss that has a way higher level than the protagonist. Also there's a mysterious girl that appeared whenever he puts in the game.

This has been on my mind ever since I first read it and it has been haunting me ever since. Any help would be appreciated. TY

Comment: Do you maybe remmember some of the settings? maybe a drawstyle or name of a protagonist. Or some sort of specific term they used inside of the manga ?

Answer (score 4):

*Gamerz heaven*

From wikipedia:

> Soon after starting the game, Kaito is attacked by the class president, Ogura. Ogura falls to Kaito and vanishes from the Second Zone. Now no one believes that Ogura ever existed except for Kaito's best friend Kawashima, who loves video games just as much as Kaito. Later Kaito eventually convinces other friends Rio, and Ren, who didn't believe him until a "meteor" hits the center of Tokyo, which was actually the work of the first area boss of Gamerz Heaven, Rush.

Regarding the mysterious girl:

> Upon reaching this strange new world, Kaito discovers a *boy* known as the "navigator", aptly dubbed "Nata". In Gamerz Heaven the real world is referred to as the "Second Zone". All enemies in Gamerz Heaven are after Nata and Kaito can only beat the game by saving him.